# Twitter videos not displaying in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, twitter, webview

I am trying to display a twitter video using embedded code in the android native webview. I have included the script `<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`. When the twitter data is loaded, it shows the text only and then it disappears and shows up a blank page. I am getting the below error in the LogCat.

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to display 'https://twitter.com/i/videos/tweet/816124923311595520?embed_source=clientlib&player_id=0&rpc_init=1&language_code=en' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors *".", source: about:blank (0)
```

I have added the below code also

```
descriptionview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
descriptionview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
descriptionview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, Message resultMsg)
    {
        WebView newWebView = new WebView(getContext());
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(newWebView);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();
        return true;
    }
});
```

I am still getting the same blank page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter video not loading android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978021/twitter-video-not-loading-android-webview)

Answer (score 4):

I have loaded the webpage with the base url and it worked.

```
            descriptionview.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://twitter.com",htmlheading +document.toString()+htmlffooter, "text/html", "utf-8","");
```

Comment: Very nice! This saved me!