# Twitter video not loading android webview

Tags: android, webview

When playing twitter video in android web view it shows the message 'by playing this video you agree to the Twitter use of cookies' and video is not played after that.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
} else
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
}
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlTemplate, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Post code, what you did for it?

Comment: not in the comment, update with your question so that people could see.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is disabled in a WebView by default.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

**UPDATED:**

Use TweetView for Native Videos
[Launching native video support for Twitter Kit](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/a/2015/launching-native-video-support-for-twitter-kit.html)

Comment: actually if twitter video is of youtube its loading but native twitter video is not loading.

Comment: have you checked by enabling the javascript in web view

Comment: yes not working. all other videos are working except twitter native videos.

Comment: when i click play button it gives the message- by playing this video you agree to the Twitter use of cookies and when i click ok nothing happens

Comment: @Nitin Sharma , Please have a look at the link above in updated answer describes nearly the same problem as yours.

Comment: this is for sdk but my problem is in webview

Comment: what link are you using to get twitter video

Comment: it comes in <blockquote> tag in rss feed and i use http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js in html script to load it.

Answer (score 0):

Call loadDataWithBaseURL instead of loadData, like this:

loadDataWithBaseURL("https://mywebsite.com", mContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);